# Как ввести с клавиатуры параметр в bat файле

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, dos

При открытии батника пользователь должен ввести название папки которой он хочет создать , далее создается папка. 
Как это написать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
set /p name=enter folder name:
mkdir %name%
```